# Create dataframe from other dataframe with intermediate calculations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have some data in a pandas dataframe that I want to work with.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a',10,5],['a',12,6],['b',4,2],['b',5,10]],
...                   columns=['id','val','val2']))
```

So the dataframe looks something like this:

```
>>> df
    id   val   val2
0   a    10    5
1   a    12    6
2   b    4     2
3   b    5     10
```

What I want to achieve is a dataframe containing the `id` values as column names and `val` and `val2` as row names, where the values shall be composed the following way:

1. Build the mean value for value columns based on `id`, leaving something like

   ```
   id   mean-val   mean-val2
   a    11         5.5
   b    4.5        6
   ```
2. Calculate the percentage of `mean-val` and `mean-val2` on the sum of both values based on `id` (e.g. `11 / (11+5.5) * 100 = 66.67`), rendering

   ```
   id    perc-val   perc-val2
   a     66.67      33.33
   b     42.86      57.14
   ```

The final dataframe shall look like this:

```
>>> new_df
       a       b
val    66.67   42.86
val2   33.33   57.14
```

#### My approach

I'm quite inexperienced with pandas, so it took me a while to get an unsatisfying approach.

```
>>> idx = ['val','val2']
>>> lst = [df.groupby('id')[index].mean() for index in idx]
>>> df_new = pd.DataFrame(
...     [[x/y*100 for x, y in zip(lst2,sum(lst))] for lst2 in lst],
...     index=idx, columns=df['id'].unique())
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it is guaranteed that either the columns or the rows are named in the right order, or if it's possible that, e.g., the `a` column is named `b` and vice versa.

So my actual question is if there is a nicer, cleaner, safer and maybe more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

1. If you're taking the mean over every column, you don't have to specify the column names
2. You can vectorize your division using `DataFrame.div` (or the division operator `__div__`)

```
v = df.groupby('id').mean()
v.T / v.sum(1) * 100          # thanks to @fuglede
# v.div(v.sum(1), axis=0).T   # thanks to @Scott Boston

id            a          b
val   66.666667  42.857143
val2  33.333333  57.142857
```

Comment: Or, ever so slightly shorter, `v.T/v.sum(1)*100`.

Comment: No worries. (Note that your point 2. is not so relevant anymore.)

Comment: `dfm.div(dfm.sum(1), axis=0).T` I think runs faster in this case.

Comment: This is what I like about python. Thanks all, that helped a lot.